# token is passed via authorization but deleted after the authentication and cannot pass to the protected route . the token appear to be undefined

Tags: node.js, ajax, jwt, local-storage, ejs

My Login controller to check the validations before submitting the page

```
static async signin(req, res, next) {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    const sql1 = `SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='${email}'`;
    // localStorage.setItem('item', 'mwafrika');
    db.query(sql1, (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (rows.length > 0) {
        const comparePass = bcryptjs.compareSync(password, rows[0].password);
        if (!comparePass) {
          res.send({ err: 'password not valid' });
        } else {
          const data = {
            id: rows[0].id,
            email: rows[0].email,
            password: rows[0].password,
          };

          jwt.sign(data, process.env.SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '1h' }, (err, token) => {
            // req.session.userSession = token;
            res.send({
              token,
            });
          });
        }
      } else {
        res.send({
          err: 'You are not registered, please signup to login',
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

my product controller to get data from the database

```
static async getAll(req, res) {
    const fromPage = '/api/v1/post';

    // CheckLog.connection(req.session.userSession, req, res, fromPage, goLoginPage,() => {});

    const sql3 = 'SELECT * FROM produits';
    db.query(sql3, (err, rows, fields) => {
      if (err) return res.send({ err });
      // res.send({
      //   data: rows,
      // });
      res.render('checkout', {
        data: rows,

      });
    });
  }
```

my middleware to verify the token before accessing the protected route

```
  import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
    import dotenv from 'dotenv';

    dotenv.config();

    class Token {
      static async authorizeAccess(req, res, next) {
        try {
          const token = req.headers.authorization;
          // req.session.token = token;
          console.log(`mwafrikkke ${token}`);

          if (!token) return res.status(400).send({ status: 'error', message: 'please login to get access to this route' });
          const decoded = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
          req.user = decoded;
          console.log(req.user);
          return next();
        } catch (error) {
          return res.status(400).send({ status: 'error', message: 'you are not Autorized' });
        }
      }
    }

    export default Token.authorizeAccess;
```

my Ajax call and save the token to local storage in client-side

```
 const signupBtn = document.getElementById('login');
signupBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  const userEmail = document.getElementById('loginEmail').value;
  const userPassword = document.getElementById('loginPassword').value;

  $.ajax({
    url: '/api/v1/auth/signin',
    method: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
    data: {
      email: userEmail,
      password: userPassword,
      // token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    },
    success(res) {
      // post details method
      localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
      console.log(`jossss${localStorage.getItem('token')}`);
      // window.location.href = 'http://localhost:7000/api/v1/products';
      if (res.token !== undefined) {
        $.ajax({
          url: '/api/v1/products',
          method: 'GET',
          contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
          headers: {
            Authorization: localStorage.getItem('token'),
          },
          success(res1) {
            document.location = '../products';
          },
        });
      } else {
        document.location = '../auth/signin';
      }
    },
  });
});
```

my login form to be used when submiting the form

```
<section id="form"><!--form-->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-sm-offset-1">
                <div class="login-form"><!--login form-->
                    <h2>Login to your account</h2>
                    <form action="/api/v1/auth/signin" method="POST">
                        <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" id="loginEmail" name="email" required />
                        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" id="loginPassword" name="password" required />
                        <span>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox">  
                            Keep me signed in
                        </span>
                        <button type="submit" id="login" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
                    </form>
                </div><!--/login form-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section><!--/form-->
```

this is the image showing the deletion of the token after being shown

[image]
[image]

this is my image of denying access

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the token in `authozation` header via this code of the middleware: `const token = req.headers.authorization;`

Please do so while making a jax request, just like this one:

```
headers: {
           authorization: localStorage.getItem('token'),
         },
```

**PS**: Make sure that the header you set in the ajax request look the same as the one you use to receive in your middlware on server.

Please let me know if it persists.

Comment: hello man. the solution you provided me yesterday didn't work. the problem I have is that I get the token on the server-side but it gets deleted again. in my middleware function.

this is my github repository : please have a look.

https://github.com/mwafrika/ufundi